# how to update the border color for fundamental ngx token component

Tags: css, angular, sap-fiori

I am trying to use the fundamental ngx token component (https://sap.github.io/fundamental-ngx/#/core/token) in my angular project. The default border is gray, I want to change it to green. I tried to apply style as follows:

```html
<fd-token class="green-border">Bibendum</fd-token>
```

```css
.green-border {
   border: 2px solid green; 
}
```

But It doesn't work. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the border color of the inner span with class `fd-token` as follows:

```
fd-token .fd-token {
    border: 2px solid green !important;
}
```